# How to pass the pointer of main Dlg from a thread to a function inside in MFC

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, pointers, mfc

There are two Thread sharing a funciton. I want to show information in Dlg when I run the function. But I don't know how to pass the pointer of main Dlg. When I run the following code ,it shows ERROR 2061.

XXXTab.h

```
static void Snap(CBoxUnstackingDlg *CMFCAppDlg);

static UINT __cdecl MtA(LPVOID lpParam);
static UINT __cdecl MtB(LPVOID lpParam);
```

XXXTab.cpp

````
void CThirdTab::Snap(CBoxUnstackingDlg *CMFCAppDlg)```
{
}

UINT __cdecl CThirdTab::MtA(LPVOID lpParam)
{
   CBoxUnstackingDlg *CMFCAppDlg = (CBoxUnstackingDlg *)lpParam;
   Snap(CMFCAppDlg );
}

UINT __cdecl CThirdTab::MtB(LPVOID lpParam)
{
   CBoxUnstackingDlg *CMFCAppDlg = (CBoxUnstackingDlg *)lpParam;
   Snap(CMFCAppDlg );
}
````

Comment: Sharing UI objects across threads is going to have you suffer. Choosing the wrong calling convention for the [ThreadProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms686736(v=vs.85)) functions isn't going to help. If you need to update the UI in response to events in a different thread, send a message from the worker thread to the UI thread. Though the question, as asked, isn't answerable. We need to see a [mcve], including the full, unabridged error diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason is two headers include each other. Making the function Snap out of class Thirdtab can fix the problem.